# Using Docker image of Streamlit app on DigitalOcean droplet through Nginx Web Server

Tags: postgresql, docker, nginx, digital-ocean, streamlit

I have a Streamlit & Python multi-page application that also uses a Postgres database and has login authentication running perfectly on my local Ubuntu computer.  My next step now that the login application is working, is to move it to the cloud so that my client can use it.

I've gotten the database moved to a DigitalOcean Postgres database and it works great with the app still on my local computer via the connection string in SQLAlchemy.  Next, in preparation for putting the app on a DigitalOcean Ubuntu "droplet" server, I created a Docker image of the app so that I don't need to deal with all the environment dependency setups on the droplet.  The Docker image runs great on my PC off of the DigitalOcean database.  So I pushed the image to a private DockerHub repository and, from my droplet, have pulled this image into the droplet after setting up the Docker engine on the droplet.  As a test, it starts fine in the Ubuntu droplet using
`$ docker run -p 8501:8501 {imagename}:{tag}`
with the normal streamlit prompt of:

```
"You can now view the Streamlit App in your browser. 
URL: http://localhost:8501.
```

I've then installed the Nginx web server and configured it to direct port 8501 out to port 80 and restarted it.  My modified Nginx default file that's in /etc/nginx/sites-available is:

```
# file located /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8501; # Ensure this is the port Streamlit runs on
#           proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
```

Everything is started and in my browser set to my droplet's IP address, I get the beginnings of a Streamlit page with a "Please wait..." box.  But that's it.  It just sits there.

In a separate tab for the DigitalOcean console, looking at the server statistic graphs of the droplet, the CPU, memory, disk, network bandwidth graphs are all in the normal ranges.  So the droplet isn't being overtaxed.

I feel like I'm very close to having this completed but I just don't know where to look to find the problem.  Is Nginx configured wrong?

I've used a gradual approach to migrating the app to the cloud to ensure that each step checked out.  1) database moved to cloud & application tested, 2) application containerized in Docker & application tested, 3) container image moved to cloud server and verified that it starts even if I can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

More trial and error, I had commented out "proxy_http_version 1.1;" in the Nginx default file because that line was not present in the location version that was given to me by ChatGPT.  Uncommenting that line totally fixed the problem and the application is running great.